# Is it possible to style rows using hex or rgb colors or use even/odd attributes in spreadsheet gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, spreadsheet

I want to style my Excel table using spreadsheet gem.

I want to make my table look as in mine view, like this:

[image]

Here is mine formatting code:

```
    header_format = Spreadsheet::Format.new :color => :black,
                               :weight => :bold,
                               :size => 10
```

**DOCUMENTATION:** http://spreadsheet.rubyforge.org/files/GUIDE_txt.html

Can I do it using spreadsheet gem **OR** I need to use only standard colors ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this post - http://andisxp.blogspot.com/2011/12/export-to-excel-with-spreadsheet-gem.html

```
  Instead of modifying the gem though, I would suggest using the following two 
  lines at   startup, they modify constants which isn't very nice but maybe 
  preferable to modifying the gem just to get some color working.

  Spreadsheet::Excel::Internals::SEDOC_ROLOC.update(:blue_gray => 0x001f)
  Spreadsheet::Column.singleton_class::COLORS << :blue_gray
```